# Form Validation error on Yii Framework?

Tags: php, yii

I'm new on Yii, I have Try Crud and succes. now try to create validation but Still error.

here my script
**Model:Buku.php**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('judul, penulis'),
            array('judul', 'length','max'=>50),
            array('penulis', 'length', 'max'=>50),
            array('judul,penulis', 'on'=>'search'),
        );       

    }
```

**Controller: BukuController.php**

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Buku;
        if(isset($_POST['Buku']))
        {
            $model->judul    =$_POST['Buku']['judul'];
            $model->penulis  =$_POST['Buku']['penulis'];
            $model->save();

            /*if($model->save())
            {
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('Succes', "Data berhasil Disimpan");
                $this->redirect(array('index'));
            }*///end of

        }//end if isset
        $this->render('create',array('model'=>$model));
    }//end of class
```

**View: create.php**

```
<div class="form">

    <h2>Add Data</h2>
    <?php echo CHtml::beginForm(array('buku/create'));?>

    <?php 

    echo CHtml::errorSummary($model);
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model,'judul');?>
        <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'judul','');?>
        <?php echo CHtml::errorSummary($model,'judul');?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model,'penulis');?>
        <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'penulis','');?>
        <?php echo CHtml::errorSummary($model,'penulis');?>
    </div>
    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit');?>
        <?php echo CHtml::endForm();?>
    </div>

</div>
```

the Error MEssage is

`Buku has an invalid validation rule. The rule must specify attributes to be validated and the validator name`

Anyone can Help This?
Im very appreciated Your answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pleas edit the first line, probably you wanted there 'required'

```
array('judul, penulis','required'),
```

And this is not needed:

```
$model->judul    =$_POST['Buku']['judul'];
$model->penulis  =$_POST['Buku']['penulis'];
```

instead you can use the mass-assignment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['Buku'];
```

Comment: 10 I have Try your advice, but still not running, on the stack trace this script is being marked :  <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'judul','');?>

Comment: what is the error message? (apa pesan errornya?) @Uchsun

Comment: @gultomicro Buku has an invalid validation rule. The rule must specify attributes to be validated and the validator name. That the Error Message

Comment: Maybe you should check if the validator names are true, then like @Pentium10 say, you have to do that step.
PS: let me know if you have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In Your Model class method rules first rule is invalid:
`array('judul, penulis')` -> no validation rule specified.
Try at least:

```
array('judul, penulis', 'required')
```

List of all Validation rules in Yii:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/

Answer (score -2):

How validation works
Parameters of a validator
Choice of validators
Scenarios
Validation rules reference

boolean : CBooleanValidator

captcha : CCaptchaValidator

compare : CCompareValidator

date : CDateValidator

default : CDefaultValueValidator

email : CEmailValidator

exist : CExistValidator

file : CFileValidator

filter : CFilterValidator

in : CRangeValidator

length : CStringValidator

numerical : CNumberValidator

match : CRegularExpressionValidator

required : CRequiredValidator

safe : CSafeValidator

type : CTypeValidator

unique : CUniqueValidator

unsafe : CUnsafeValidator

url : CUrlValidator

Selected readings
Built in validators in Yii....